# Updating Many to Many Relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working on a MVC 4 internet application that involves many to many relationship. I managed to get the many to many relationship but I am having trouble updating it.

```
public class Machine
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    //Other attributes

    public List<Task> Tasks {get; set; }
}

public class Task
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    //other attributes

    public List<Machine> Machines { get; set; }
}
```

I created some sample data and the mapping works fine as far as I am concerned.

Then I went on to create CURDs. I wanted to add a list of check-boxes for selecting tasks for the Add/Edit Machine views.

```
class MachineController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult Add(){ return View(); }

  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Add(Machine machine, string[] tasks)
  {
    //some code here
  }

  public ActionResult Edit(int id) { //some code here } 

  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Edit(Machine machine, string[] tasks)
  {
    //This method will add or remove Task objects from the list as needed & works
    UpdateMachineTasks(machine, tasks);
    //The below method fails - exception: 
        //An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key
    //db.Entry(machine).State = EntityState.Modified
    //Then I used the following from a post I found on SO
    Machine m = db.Machines.Find(machine.ID);
    db.Entry(m).CurrentValues.SetValues(machine) //On debug, `machine` has the proper `Task` 
    db.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

The `Add(Machine machine, string[] tasks) { //... }` works fine. 
When I open the url `/Edit/1` the fields are properly populated and also the check boxes are properly checked.
I change values (strings and ints) and also the check boxes and save.

Then I notice that the checkboxes are not updated but other vlues are.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a junction table http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table to get around your many to many relation.

The problem may be that your system doesn't like the many to many relationship.

Comment: The entity framework creats a junction table for us. every thing is ok except the Update. The junction table is what seems not to get updated.